# Splitting of progress bar

Tags: php, html, mysql, progress-bar

I am working on an education based module where a list is shown for "Module 1" to "Module 5". Each "Module" has 'n' number of chapters. Now I want to show a progress bar which shows the study duration of each chapter in that "Module". I am unable to split the progress bar, into 'n' numbers(equal to chapters for each module) and to show reading time of each chapter in that 'Module'.

Here is my code:

```
 <td align='center'> 
        <?php
 while ($j<=$chapters){ //$chapters has count of chapters for each module and $j is increment variable initialized to 1 at start.
       echo '<progress value="150" max="500">'; $j=$j+1;}        ?>
     </td>
```

Comment: We need way more information, like where is the amount of chapters stored and where the finished chapters.

Comment: Thanks for the time spared for me. The issue is a little tricky. I want to print as many progress bars as there are chapters for each module. I got one progress bar here. I am editing the code once again . Please take a look

Comment: Yes like I said we need more information to help you with that. Basically, you need to loop for each necessary progress bar. This means you need some kind of array with the information.

Comment: Just updated the code. Please take a look.. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I´m sorry to say it but you need to add many more informations. With the current informations it should create enough progressbars. Now you have to insert the different durations and the time already finished. This informations have to be stored somewhere. Try to add more from your code, at the moment it is not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Like Thamaraiselvam said, you seem to be confused with quotes:

```
<td align="center"> 
<?php
echo '<progress value="'.$seconds.'" max="'.$total_time.'">'; 
?>
</td>
```

PHP can use either single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`), but in your case, it makes more sense to use single quotes. This is because HTML needs double quotes. If you use double quotes, you'd have to escape the HTML double quotes, otherwise, it would be interpreted as the end/beginning of a string by PHP (confusing, I know).

Just a piece of advice, it's shorter to use:

```
<td align="center"> 
  <?= '<progress value="'.$seconds.'" max="'.$total_time.'">' ?>
</td>
```

Or even:

```
<td align="center"> 
  <progress value="<?= $seconds ?>" max="<?= $total_time ?>">
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time spared for me. The issue is a little tricky. I want to print as many progress bars as there are chapters for each module. I got one progress bar here. I am editing the code once again . Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this, seems you are confused with quotes

```
<td align='center'> 
<?php
echo "<progress value='" . $seconds . "' max='" . $total_time ."'>"; 
?>
</td>
```

Comment: The problem is that with this code HTML attributes are not placed within quotes. It might not be a problem if the values are just pure integers, but it's best practice to always quote attributes (and with double quotes).

Comment: You are right. But browsers like chrome adding quotes after the `=` of the `attr` even $second is a pure integer. anyway, thanks for that @Louis-MarieMatthews

Comment: Thanks for the time spared for me. The issue is a little tricky. I want to print as many progress bars as there are chapters for each module. I got one progress bar here. I am editing the code once again . Please take a look.